# How to share a global spark session?

Tags: apache-spark

Actually I am working on a project which includes a workflow which consists of multiple tasks and single task consists of multiple components. 
for eg. 
In join , we need 4 components. 2 for input ( consider two table join) , 1 for join logic and 1 for output ( writing back to hdfs ).
This is one task. , similarly "sort" can be another task.

suppose a workflow with these two tasks and which are linked i.e
after performing join , we are using output of join in our sorting task.
But "join" and "sort" invoke separate "spark sessions".

So the flow is like , one spark session is created for join using spark submit , output is saved in hdfs and current spark session is closed. For the sort another session is created using spark submit and output stored at hdfs by join task is fetched for sorting.

But the problem is there is a overhead of fetching the data from hdfs.
So is there any way I can share a session for different tasks between two spark-submit. So that i will not loose my result dataframe from join and which can be directly used in my next spark-submit of sorting.

So basically I have multiple spark-submit associated with different task . But I want to retain my result in dataframe in memory so that I need not to persist it and can be used in another linked task ( spark-submit)

Answer (score 0):

The spark session builder has a function to get or create the SparkSession.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("AzuleneTest")
    .getOrCreate()
```

But reading your description you may be better off passing dataframes between between the functions (which hold a reference to a spark session).   This avoids creating multiple instances of spark. For example

```
//This is run within a single spark application
val df1 = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket/1/")
val df2 = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket/1/")
val df3 = df1.join(df2,"id")

df3.write.parquet("s3://bucket/3/")
```

Comment: could you elaborate a little. What I need is to share the spark session within linked "tasks"

Comment: Do "tasks" run in different jvms/drivers?  If so its impossible to share state between them without reloading the data from storage.  Depending on how you're connecting to your cluster some tools optionally keep a long lived session around for example livy.

Comment: so if a single user is creating all the tasks and he knows all the information such as number of tasks . can i do my job using Livy ?

Comment: I am not getting whether spark-submit and jvm/driver are related ?

Comment: Spark submit always creates a new jvm with runs the driver which contains the sparksession information and in general runs everything in spark.